# Can't go into edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Help this is so silly is it me? What am I doing wrong? I made of gif of what is going on below, hopefully i'm doing something wrong.

https://gyazo.com/be75d6f44431243bee556584d811efc0

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to turn ON **Viewport Overlays** button next to display modes on 3d view header ...

[image]